# не получается инициализировать массив структур через список

Tags: c, массивы, struct

```
struct numbers
    {
        char s[5][5];

    };
    struct numbers nums[2] = {
        {
            { {' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '}, {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}, {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}, {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}, {'|', '_', '_', '_', '|'} },
            { {' ', ' ', ' ', '/', '|'}, {' ', ' ', '/', ' ', '|'}, {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}, {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}, {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'} },
            
        }
    };
```

Хочу создать структуру из пяти массивов с массивами из пяти char символов. Выдает ошибку `extra brace group at end of initializer`  на второй элемент nums(состоящий из 5 массивов символов)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте скобки правильно:

```
struct numbers nums[2] =
{
    { // nums[0]
        {  // nums[0].s
            {' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', '_', '_', '_', '|'}
        }
    },
    { // nums[1]
        {  // nums[1].s
            {' ', ' ', ' ', '/', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', '/', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}
        }
    },
};
```

Специально немного иначе форматировал текст, чтоб было понятнее.

Для сравнения — а вот как выглядит ваше объявление. Разницу видите?

```
struct numbers nums[2] =
{
    { // nums[0]
        { // // nums[0].s
            {' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {'|', '_', '_', '_', '|'}
        },
        { // ???!!!
            {' ', ' ', ' ', '/', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', '/', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'}
        },
    } // end of nums[0]
};
```

Comment: да спасибо, разница видна, понимал что ошибся где-то в скобках, просто отказался от такой структуры в проекте

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...

Answer (score 0):

От вложенных скобок можно избавиться:

```
struct numbers
{
    char s[5][5];

};
struct numbers nums[2] =
{
    ' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '
,   '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
,   '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
,   '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
,   '|', '_', '_', '_', '|'

,   ' ', ' ', ' ', '/', '|'
,   ' ', ' ', '/', ' ', '|'
,   ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
,   ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
,   ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'
};
```

Кроме того, раз тут инициализируется массив `char` c чем-то вроде псевдографики, то наверное имеет смысл инициализировать его посредством строкового литерала:

```
struct numbers
{
    char s[26];
};
struct numbers nums[2] =
{
    " ___ "
    "|   |"
    "|   |"
    "|   |"
    "|___|"

,   "   /|"
    "  / |"
    "    |"
    "    |"
    "    |"
};
```